# Looking for a module to login any social media

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I am looking for a module in python3 to make a scripts of social media.
I need module like smtplib.
But not for Gmail for another social media platforms

Comment: As far as I know, there is no single module that will let you log into any social media. But, You can easily and quickly create a python script for each social media using selenium and log in.

Comment: Thanks bro it's some helpful for me